# send an array with the use of drupal_goto()

Tags: php, drupal-7

I have two drupal nodes defined in a menu hook like following. The first page is an interface:some drupal forms what I want to do is to take submitted values from the first page through the submitt function and redirect the user to the next page and send those values with the use of the function drupal_goto().How can I add those values/ array to the drupal_goto() function and then get it and use it from the destination page( The scenario is this: page1--submitt--get submitted values---put them in one array---go to the another page and send the submitted values by the use of drupal_goto() function)

In my module module:

```
function my_module_menu() {

  $items = array();
  $items['admin/interface'] = array( // page one that is some drupal forms
    'title' => '',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('my_module_form'),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'file' => 'includes/my_module.form.inc',
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );

  $items['complete-page'] = array( // once the user is redirected to this page I want to use 
 // the sent array as an argument of the menu function: my_module_function()
    'title' => 'complete',
    //'page callback' => 'my_module_complete',
    //'page arguments' => $query,
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'page callback' => 'my_module_function',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );

  return $items;
}
function my_module_function($val){
//use the value $val
}
```

form function:

```
function my_module_form($form, &$form_state) {
 //some drupal forms
 $form['xxx'] = array(
 '#type' => 'type',
 '#value' => t('some text'),
 );
 return $form;
}
```

In my submitt function I want to take a submitted some submitted values put them in one array and send it to the next page:

```
function my_module_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    $values = array();
    $value1 =$form_state['values']['xxx'];
    $value2 =$form_state['values']['form'];
    $value3 =$form_state['values']['another_form'];
    $values[0] = $value1;
    $values[1] = $value2;
    $values[2] = $value3;
    drupal_goto('complete-page', $values);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`drupal_goto` just sends a redirect back to the browser, which means any data needs to be passed in that request, or you could store it in $_SESSION.

For example:

```
drupal_goto( 'complete-page', array( 'query' => array( 'xxx' => $form_state['values']['xxx'] ) ) );
```

or:

```
$_SESSION['complete-page']['xxx'] = $form_state['values']['xxx'];
drupal_goto( 'complete-page' );
```

The disadvantage of the first is that the submitted values are visible in the query.  The disadvantage of the second is that it pollutes your session and is a rather round-about way of getting the data to your destination (you should delete the data in your handler for *complete-page*).

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `drupal_goto` function to manage multipage forms. You face here on of the problem of doing it : to give parameters, you have to give them in the url (&param_name=param_value) or to store them into user session. You also, by calling a new form on every page, loose the Drupal's cache mechanism.

The thing is to use the `$form_state` array which comes with your form. You can store inside a page number, and then condition the returned form depending of this page number.

You will find some examples [here](http://matthewgrasmick.com/article/building-multistep-registration-form-drupal-7) or [here](http://davidsonj.com/blog/how-create-multi-step-form-drupal-7).
The better way to do it for the moment is to use the `chaostools` that you must have already installed (mandatory for a lot of modules). There's no online documentation : you should install the [advanced-help](https://drupal.org/project/advanced_help) module. Here is [an example of how to do it](http://www.nicklewis.org/using-chaos-tools-form-wizard-build-multistep-forms-drupal-6). Care, this example is for Drupal 6.